# Is there a database/library for the adjacency matrices of notable graphs in the literature?

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for a database or library that contains adjacency matrices of notable graphs from the mathematical literature such as e.g. the Petersen graph or the Frucht graph. More examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Individual_graphs.

Does anyone know of such a database/library?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are various sources of graph data - check https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12741 for a survey.

Comment: Check out networkx (https://networkx.org/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use Sage, which has an [extensive collection](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html) of graphs built in. Or the [graphs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html) known to Mathematica.